# How to check if there is empty texbox in a panel?

Tags: vb.net-2010

I want to have warning message if there is empty textbox in a panel, is there any way? please help.

Answer (score 1):

```
Function With_EmptyTextbox(ByVal p As Panel) As Boolean
    For Each t As TextBox In p.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
        If t.Text = vbNullString Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code on each one so you can show a different message each time depending on the data that should be wirten in the textbox:

```
If textbox1.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Your message here", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
End If
```

Comment: thanks sir, but I mean is, I have many textboxes on a panel, when there is one or more of the textboxes is empty it will warning just one for all.